# Pourquoi les anglophones remplacent-ils le phonème /ɛ/ par /e/ si souvent?

Tags: phonétique, voyelles

Beaucoup d'apprenants anglophones remplacent le phonème /e/ par la diphtongue anglaise /eɪ/. C'est évidemment parce que le phonème n'existe pas en anglais isolément. Cependant, je ne comprends pas pourquoi leur interprétation de ce phonème apparaît fréquemment dans les circonstances où on ne l'utilise pas. Par exemple, [cette page web](http://www.pronunciationguide.info/thebiglist.html#French) essaie d'expliquer la prononciation des noms des compositeurs étrangers. Elle indique que « Bizet » est prononcé comme /bizeɪ/ et non [/bizɛ/](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Bizet), « Rousset » comme /ʁuseɪ/ et non /ʁusɛ/

Les anglophones prononcent aussi les noms propres « Bossuet », [« Condorcet »](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Condorcet), « Genet », etc. ou les mots comme [« fait »](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fait), [« lait »](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/lait), [« maison »](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/maison), ou [« raison »](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/raison) dans cette manière.

Qu'est-ce que c'est la raison pour cette substitution?

Comment: En anglais, on ne peut pas mettre le phonème /ɛ/ à la fin d'un mot. Donc /bizɛ/, /rusɛ/, /fɛ/, /lɛ/, sont des prononciations impossibles.

Comment: @Peter C'est ça, et semblablement pour les autres voyelles dites  « relâchées ». Pour ce qui est de *Delibes*, on pourrait supposer que les anglophones auraient tendance à trop galliciser, pour ainsi dire, et d'imaginer des accents aigus surtout dans les noms propres...

Comment: Où as tu lu ou entendu /deɪlib/ ?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Pardon, dans mon hâte j’ai interprété incorrectement la transcription. J’ai rencontré quelques anglophones qui prononcent « Debussy » dans cette façon, et j’ai confondu probablement les circonstances.

Comment: Ben je vais me re-regarder le spectacle de Paul Taylor sur YouTube :-)

Answer (score 1):

Quand l'alphabet phonétique international a été créé, le son `ɛ` dans « bet » était écrit `e`, comme dans « aimé », parce qu'en anglais, c'était plus fermé. Cependant, après des décennies, on a décidé d'utiliser le symbole `ɛ` pour « b**e**t », et il y a quelques dictionnaires qui rendent `eɪ` comme `e`, parce que dans quelques dialectes anglais, `eɪ` n'est pas aussi long.

Donc, je pense que l'utilisation de `e` pour `ɛ` est due à la tradition.

Comment: Most people learn French without ever learning IPA, so I don't understand how the history of IPA could provide an explanation of the incorrect pronunciation.

Comment: Most French dictionaries seem to have it, though. You don't get taught it in school, but you eventually get a feel for it.